# How to count number of people for each month, who was on internship, if we know dates of internship

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis

First of all, sorry for bad title - I can't figure out how to write generalized formulation of my problem.
I have a table in PostgreSQL with users and dates of their internships. It looks like this:

| user_id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | December 22, 2019 | June 29, 2020 |
| 2 | March 8, 2020 | September 8, 2020 |
| 3 | May 21, 2020 | November 21, 2020 |

From this I need to calculate for each month, how many people were on internship during this month. I only need to calculate full months (if internship actually started on December 22, 2019, I will calculate from January 2022. If internship were finished at June 29, 2020, I will calculate till May 2020.
Finally I need this table:

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Jan-20 | 1 |
| Feb-20 | 1 |
| Mar-20 | 1 |
| Apr-20 | 2 |
| May-20 | 2 |
| Jun-20 | 2 |
| Jul-20 | 2 |
| Aug-20 | 2 |
| Sep-20 | 1 |
| Oct-20 | 1 |

For making it absolutely clear, this is how I got it:

| Month | user_1 | user_2 | user_3 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-20 | 1 |  |  | 1 |
| Feb-20 | 1 |  |  | 1 |
| Mar-20 | 1 |  |  | 1 |
| Apr-20 | 1 | 1 |  | 2 |
| May-20 | 1 | 1 |  | 2 |
| Jun-20 |  | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Jul-20 |  | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Aug-20 |  | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Sep-20 |  |  | 1 | 1 |
| Oct-20 |  |  | 1 | 1 |

My idea is to:

1. Reshape my initial table, so it will look like this:

| user_id | date | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | December 22, 2019 | start |
| 1 | June 29, 2020 | end |
| 2 | March 8, 2020 | start |
| 2 | September 8, 2020 | end |
| 3 | May 21, 2020 | start |
| 3 | November 21, 2020 | end |

2. Generate series between each start and end event:

| user_id | month |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan-20 |
| 1 | Feb-20 |
| 1 | Mar-20 |
| 1 | Apr-20 |
| 1 | May-20 |
| 2 | Apr-20 |
| 2 | May-20 |
| 2 | Jun-20 |
| 2 | Jul-20 |
| 2 | Aug-20 |
| 3 | Jun-20 |
| 3 | Jul-20 |
| 3 | Aug-20 |
| 3 | Sep-20 |
| 3 | Oct-20 |

3. Using count() GROUP BY month

Unfortunately, I have problems with 1 and 2 clauses.

I don't know how to reshape the table in PostgreSQL. In Pandas I would use 'stack' function. For my case I can't find the appropriate function.

Even if I can reshape it, I don't understand how to make series of month for each user (shown above).

Please advise, what can be done here to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this query should do the job considering your table as `test` :

```
SELECT to_char(d.date, 'Mon-YY') AS month, count(*) AS count
  FROM
     ( SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('month', min(start_date)), date_trunc('month', max(end_date)), interval '1 month') :: date AS date
         FROM test
     ) AS d
 INNER JOIN test AS t
    ON daterange(t.start_date, t.end_date, '[]') && daterange(d.date, (d.date + interval '1 month') :: date)
 WHERE daterange(t.start_date, t.end_date, '[]') @> daterange(d.date, (d.date + interval '1 month') :: date)
 GROUP BY d.date
```

- The first sub query calculate the months covered in table `test`.
- The `JOIN` clause calculates the intersections between the months and the date interval for each user
- The `WHERE` clause filters the rows where the date interval for a user corresponds to a full months.

**Result** :

| month | count |
| --- | --- |
| Jan-20 | 1 |
| Feb-20 | 1 |
| Mar-20 | 1 |
| Apr-20 | 2 |
| May-20 | 2 |
| Jun-20 | 2 |
| Jul-20 | 2 |
| Aug-20 | 2 |
| Sep-20 | 1 |
| Oct-20 | 1 |

see results in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xjPR--T-)

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to

- generate a calendar table using `GENERATE_SERIES`
- joining the calendar table with your original table on date ranges
- aggregating to count users for each month

```
WITH calendar AS (
    SELECT DATE('2020-01-01') + (num_months::text || ' month')::interval AS months
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, 11) AS num_months
)
SELECT c.months, COUNT(user_id) AS cnt
FROM calendar c
INNER JOIN tab 
        ON c.months BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('month', tab.start_) + INTERVAL '1 month' AND DATE_TRUNC('month', tab.end_) - INTERVAL '1 month'
GROUP BY c.months
ORDER BY c.months
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jFSt2brMAT83sSfuMbo9VL/1).

---

If you're using a PostgreSQL legacy version, you can obtain the calendar table with a recursive query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE calendar AS (
    SELECT '2020-01-01'::timestamp AS months, 
           0 AS num_months
    
    UNION ALL 
  
    SELECT months + INTERVAL '1 month' AS months,
           num_months + 1 AS num_months
    FROM calendar
    WHERE num_months +1 <= 12
)
SELECT c.months, COUNT(user_id) AS cnt
FROM calendar c
INNER JOIN tab 
        ON c.months BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('month', tab.start_) + INTERVAL '1 month' AND DATE_TRUNC('month', tab.end_) - INTERVAL '1 month'
GROUP BY c.months
ORDER BY c.months
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jFSt2brMAT83sSfuMbo9VL/2).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I accomplished this:

- Generated a calendar table using `generate_series`
- Truncated the `start` and `end` dates to ensure we are only including instances where a full month of the internship was completed.
- Performed a `cross join` to generate a `cartesian product set`.
- Finally, add the `WHERE` predicate to include instances where the `date_mm` is between the truncated `start` and `end` dates.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT a.date_mm AS MONTH,
       count(b.user_id) AS COUNT
FROM
  (SELECT date_mm :: date
   FROM generate_series('2020-01-01', '2023-01-01', '1 month' :: interval) date_mm) a
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT a.user_id,
          a.start,
         /* start_next_fom = first day of next month */ 
         (date_trunc('month', a.start) + interval '1 month') AS start_next_fom,
         a.end,
         /* end_last_eom = last day of last month */
         (date_trunc('month', a.end) - interval '1 day') AS end_last_eom
   FROM users a) b
WHERE a.date_mm BETWEEN b.start_next_fom AND b.end_last_eom
GROUP BY a.date_mm
ORDER BY a.date_mm
```

**Result:**

```
|      month | count |
|------------|-------|
| 2020-01-01 |     1 |
| 2020-02-01 |     1 |
| 2020-03-01 |     1 |
| 2020-04-01 |     2 |
| 2020-05-01 |     2 |
| 2020-06-01 |     2 |
| 2020-07-01 |     2 |
| 2020-08-01 |     2 |
| 2020-09-01 |     1 |
| 2020-10-01 |     1 |
```

**SQL Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9f9f3/37

Answer (score 1):

Example with date calendar as subquery - number sequence (10*12) - 10 year.
Test data:

```
create table test (user_id integer, start_date date, end_date date) ;
insert into test values
(1, 'December 22, 2019',    'June 29, 2020')
,(2,    'March 8, 2020',    'September 8, 2020')
,(3,    'May 21, 2020', 'November 21, 2020') --june-october
,(4,    'May 31, 2020', 'November 30, 2020') --june-november
,(5,    'May 01, 2020', 'May 31, 2020') -- 1 full month - may
,(6,    'May 01, 2020', 'May 30, 2020') -- part of month  - null
,(7,    'May 05, 2020', 'May 30, 2020') -- part of month - null
,(8,    'May 05, 2020', 'May 31, 2020') -- part of month - null
,(9,    'May 05, 2020', 'June 6, 2020') -- part of month - null
,(10,   'May 05, 2020', 'July 6, 2020') -- part of 2 month -june
,(11,   'Jan 01, 2018', 'Dec 31, 2020') -- full 3 year
  ;
```

Main query:

```
SELECT user_id,start_date,end_date,mn monthNum
  ,to_char(case when date_trunc('month', start_date)=start_date 
                then  (start_date+cast((mn-1) ||' month' as interval))
           else (start_date+cast(mn ||' month' as interval))
           end, 'YY-mm-Mon') AS month
  ,case when date_trunc('month', start_date)=start_date 
        then  (start_date+cast((mn-1) ||' month' as interval))
   else (start_date+cast(mn ||' month' as interval))
   end date
FROM  test AS t 
left join --series of 120 numbers (month)
  (select yn*12+mn as mn
   from (select * from(values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(9),(10),(11),(12))tm(mn))tm -- month
       ,(select * from(values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(9),(10))ty(yn)) ty --years
  )mm
  on case when date_trunc('month', start_date)=start_date -- first day of month
        then  (start_date+cast((mn-1) ||' month' as interval))
      else (start_date+cast(mn ||' month' as interval))
      end
  <=
    case when end_date
              =(date_trunc('month', end_date) 
                           + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day') --eomonth
         then end_date
    else (end_date-cast(extract(day from end_date) ||' day' as interval))
    end
ORDER BY user_id,mn
```

Somewhat complicated to check **start_date is first day of month** and **end_date is last day of month**
[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/t_Im0lXi)